# Why I can't take the content of a tag using XPath in a Java method?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jdom, jdom-2

I am very new in **XPath** and I have the following problem:

I have a Java method that receives data from a webservices and these data are in a XML document, so I have to use XPath to take a specific value inside this XML result document.

In particular I have that this is the entire XML output provided by my web service (the web service response):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <getConfigSettingsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <getConfigSettingsResult><![CDATA[<root>
                        <status>
                            <id>0</id>
                            <message></message>
                        </status>

<drivers>
<drive id="tokenId 11">
  <shared-secret>Shared 11</shared-secret>
  <encoding>false</encoding>
  <compression />
</drive>
<drive id="tokenId 2 ">
  <shared-secret>Shared 2  </shared-secret>
  <encoding>false</encoding>
  <compression>false</compression>
</drive>
</drivers>
</root>]]></getConfigSettingsResult>
      </getConfigSettingsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now in a Java class I perform the following operations:

```
XPath xPath;                        // An utility class for performing XPath calls on JDOM nodes

Element objectElement;              // An XML element
                        //xPath = XPath.newInstance("s:Envelope/s:Body/getVersionResponse/getVersionResult");

            try {
                // XPath selection:
                xPath = XPath.newInstance("s:Envelope/s:Body");
                xPath.addNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                objectElement = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);

                if (objectElement != null) {
                    result = objectElement.getValue();
                    System.out.println("RESULT:");
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
            } catch (JDOMException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and the result of printing the content of the **result** variable is this output:

```
RESULT:
<root>
                        <status>
                            <id>0</id>
                            <message></message>
                        </status>

<drivers>
<drive id="tokenId 11">
  <shared-secret>Shared 11</shared-secret>
  <encoding>false</encoding>
  <compression />
</drive>
<drive id="tokenId 2 ">
  <shared-secret>Shared 2  </shared-secret>
  <encoding>false</encoding>
  <compression>false</compression>
</drive>
</drivers>
</root>
```

Now my problem is that I want to access only ad the content of the **0** tag, so I want that (in this case) my **result** variable have to contain the **0** value.

But I can't, I have try to change the previous XPath selection with:

```
xPath = XPath.newInstance("s:Envelope/s:Body/s:status/s:id");
```

But doing in this way I obtain that my **objectElement** is **null**

Why? What am I missing? What have I to do to obtain that mu result variable contains the content of the **id** tag?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Are you using JDOM 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours "root" node in "CDATA" section. Whole section interpetated as text, and you cannot search it by xPath. You can get text from "objectElement.getValue()", parse it like new XML, and then get tag "id" value with new xPath. Also you can search "objectElement.getValue()" for tag  "id" value with regular expression.

Comment: mmm what do you mean when say to me that my "root" node in "CDATA" section?

Comment: and what have I to do to "parse it like a new XML"?

Comment: You can see "<![CDATA[<root>" in yours XML. More details about CDATA here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp You can parse text from "objectElement.getValue()"in the same way like you parsing whole "<s:Envelope" document.

Comment: From the perspective of your DOM, the whole block inside <![CDATA[...]> is just a chunk of text. You could take that chunk and parse it as XML and then you'd be able to run XPath on it.

Comment: @hcayless ok but what have I to do to take this chunk of text and parse it as XML?

Answer (score 0):

Really you should be using the new XPathAPI in JDOM 2.x, and taking pasha701's answer in to consideration, your code should look more like:

```
Namespace soap = Namespace.getNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
Namespace tempuri = Namespace.getNamespace("turi", ""http://tempuri.org/");
XPathExpression<Element> xpath = XPathFactory.instance().compile(
       "s:Envelope/s:Body/turi:getConfigSettingsResponse/turi:getConfigSettingsResult",
       Filters.element(), null, soap, tempuri);
Element result = xpath.evaluateFirst(documentXML);
String resultxml = result.getValue();
Document resultdoc = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader(resultxml));
Element id = resultdoc.getRootElement().getChild("status").getChild("id");
```